# C# service does not start even with Automatic option selected

Tags: c#, windows, service

I made two C# services with Startup Type - Automatic.

For the first one, I'm using this setup:

[image: Service 1]

The, for the second one

[image: Service 2]

The first one starts on boot automatically, the second one does not.
But running the 2nd one manually works.

Is there a reason for this behavior?

Note: Automatic (Delayed Start) also works for Service 2 but I'd appreciate if anyone can explain the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: i would expect it would start but maybe fail..

Comment: @BugFinder thanks for your input. I checked the event logger but there was no activity regarding Service 2.

Comment: that is very odd, ive not see windows not start a service, just because theres a login account...

Comment: @BugFinder is there other reasons why this particular service didn't get started when set to Automatic?

Comment: not that i know of unless one of its listed dependencies didnt start.. normally all services set to start do.. the only reason they arent running is either a dependency isnt finished starting, or it failed.  not all errors go to event long sometimes you need to make the log yourself

Comment: It might not be the account.  It might be something else.  Can you show us some of the code in the service?

Comment: @BugFinder oh let me try, do you recommend any methods for logging? I'm using EventLog to log if something happened with the service (e.g "Service started" note). Which also didn't popped in my event viewer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey is there something specific in the code you want to check? It's actually a huge solution, I apologize!

Comment: put some logs in right at the very start of the service or write it to a file to debug where it goes to

Comment: Then you need to isolate the problem.  Windows Services are opaque and therefore difficult to troubleshoot.  Add some logs.  Find out where the code is bombing.

Comment: It could be depending on some other service that is a delayed start. Which would make your service fail with automatic but not automatic (delayed start)

Comment: @BugFinder   I added some logs before the service starts but it doesn't get logged unless I start it on Manual. Hmmm, there is no dependencies under the Dependencies Tab as well. Tho in the code it actually uses Service 1.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'll keep trying. Thanks for giving your thoughts about it.

Comment: @PatrickMcvay  There is no dependencies under the Dependencies Tab as well. In the code it actually uses Service 1. Hope that info helps!

Comment: Have you tried setting the dependancy on service1?

Comment: @BugFinder I followed this one - http://toastergremlin.com/?p=28 but it still didnt let me start the Service2 automatically

Comment: it can only suggest it us quietly barfing on something

Comment: @BugFinder I found out that the issue was related with the domain controller in the domain I was trying to connect. It says 'We can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't available' but it connects after boot. Is there a specific setup if I the service login is setup like this? Thank you!